# Calculating overall average time taken to send a packet from source to destination when a all the nodes in the network are moving

Tags: routes, delay, analysis, ns2

I have been working on a routing protocol and now have to do some performance analysis on the protocol. In the routing protocol all the nodes are moving. Then how should I get overall delay taken to deliver a packet form source to destination. As at a specific time the nodes might be adjacent to each other and might be very far after sometime.

So how to do performance analysis related to delay in such a scenario?

I am using ns2 to simulate the protocol.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do Delay or E2E Delay - thats all.
see the following link for more information.
http://www.projectguideline.com/topic/calculating-average-time-taken-to-send-a-packet-from-source-to-destinatination